# Nx Cloud make-angular-cli-faster error: "The schematic can only be used with Angular CLI workspaces with a single project."

Tags: angular, angular-cli

When I run Nx Cloud's `make-angular-cli-faster` on my Angular project, I get the following error:

"The schematic can only be used with Angular CLI workspaces with a single project."

This is the start of the stacktrace:

```
Error: Command failed: nx g @nrwl/workspace:ng-add --preserveAngularCLILayout
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:621:11)
    at Object.execSync (child_process.js:657:15)
    at C:\Users....
```

I'm using Angular version 9.0.2 and AngularCLI version 9.0.3.

Does anyone know the fix for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, this only supports Angular CLI workspaces with one project at the moment. But multi-project support is on the roadmap.

Answer (score 3):

This can be configured in angular.json. I had end-to-end testing configured in my projects block that I needed to remove to make it work:

```
"projects": {
    "foo": {
      //...
    },
    "foo-e2e": {  <-- needed to remove this
      //...
    }
}
```